# Re-enable keyboard shortcuts in Git Bash for Windows

Tags: windows, git, keyboard-shortcuts, git-bash

I recently upgraded my Git for Windows installation to version 2.33 (by downloading the installer from https://git-scm.com).

After I did that, keyboard shortcuts no longer work in Git Bash. For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> no longer activates the window's menu, as it used to do. I can still, however, access it with the mouse:

[image: Screen shot of Git Bash window menu]

As can be seen in the screen shot, the *Edit* menu advertises various additional (standard) keyboard shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. These also worked before I upgraded my Git installation, but now none of them work.

I've tried to examine the window Properties, but shortcuts look like they ought to be enabled:

[image: Git Bash window Properties]

How do I get my keyboard shortcuts back?

Comment: Do the shortcuts work if you run the regular `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio Yes, shortcuts work in both `cmd` and PowerShell.

Comment: This is just speculation, but: perhaps you've set your "alt" key to provide "meta" functionality in bash windows, overriding its old "alt" functionality. How that would be done on *Windows*, I have no idea.

Comment: I happen to have the same behaviour than you describe. Seems to be a Linux-y thing though. For instance, I run a `cmd.exe`, and find that CTRL-M works there. I then type `wsl` to run a WSL Ubuntu session inside the command window. At this point CTRL-M becomes a carriage return and the shortcut no longer works.

Comment: FWIW, this problem seems to be introduced by Git for Windows 2.27. [This thread](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2774) seems to indicate that this change was introduced by Cygwin.